# Was I wrong to call out a link only answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

*This is not about the question as we can all agree that the question itself is very poor.*

I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403450/find-sin-value-php/46403553?noredirect=1#comment79764290_46403553) on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46403553/2263631) (now deleted; [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLdcA.png)) saying,

> This is not an answer. Please add code to your answer and not just external links.

As I felt that the answer didn't directly answer the question (quite frankly it didn't come close) and it felt like a comment. A *high rep* user then [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403450/find-sin-value-php/46403553?noredirect=1#comment79764385_46403553),

> I think it's an answer. If @Script47 really cares about providing code, why didn't s/he post it as an answer? I hate this kind of trollish, pseudo-moderator comment from low rep users.

As mentioned in my comment, my only motive was to get the answerer to raise the standard of their own answer thereby helping the community as a whole. My personal ethos has always been that if you are going to provide an answer which *slightly* nudges to questioner in to the direction of an answer, it should be a comment.

So my question is was I wrong? Can the answer be counted as a valid answer based on the [answering guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?

Comment: Please do flag comments like that. Calling someone trollish is not constructive, whatever someone's rep.

Comment: @MartijnPieters which flag would be best suited?

Comment: This is **not** a link only answer. The relevant information is to look at tailor series expansion. If the link dies, the information is still there and valid.

Comment: The question should just have been closed, I've done so now. It's the question that attracted that answer to begin with. I've converted the answer to a comment, to ensure that the question can be roomba'd.

Comment: _"Hint: look at __x__"_ is a comment at best. An answer elaborates on the hint. It explains the theory, instead of just pointing you at some word.

Comment: @Cerbrus that is exactly what I thought. However I guess others disagree...

Comment: Example: _"Hint: Look at SO's rules and guidelines"_ < That does not answer this question.

Comment: As long as a post like that gets 3 help-votes then this practice is not going to end any time soon.  Maybe we do have to acknowledge that the majority of SO users want a different kind of site, perhaps more in tune with what the company wants.  Majority rule, resistance is futile.  I'll just keep posting what *I* think is useful, puh.

Comment: @HansPassant Agreed but it's not only that, it's the fact that such a high reputation user is commenting saying that such *pseudo-moderation* is frowned upon. If the higher ups don't adhere, how can people expect the people starting out to learn or for that matter adhere to the guidelines?

Comment: "pseudo-moderator" I am more familiar with the term "backseat moderator". But I don't consider this backseat modding at all.

Comment: The suggestion alone that a 5k rep is a low-rep user rustles my jimmies. Sure there are different magnitudes, but this situation only comes out condescending. :(

Comment: At 5k rep, you've earned the right to the [moderator privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation) you have access to! The moderator actions that you are given the right to complete are not considered "pseudo-moderator" any more than if a user with more rep completes them. If a user with 5k rep shouldn't be able to add comments, then they wouldn't be granted the ability to comment. All users are supposed to help keep the site clean, not just users with really high rep!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, you were not wrong for calling out that post. "*Hint: have a look at the Taylor Expansion of sin*" is not an answer. I fully agree that we should discourage such low-effort answers. In this case, I also agree it barely even answers the question.

However, your comment could have been better. You've said:

> This is not an answer. Please add code to your answer and not just external links.

To me, this reads a little aggressive, and comes off as combative. You could have flagged the post as "not an answer", but you may have thought it did have potential. In that case, a better phrasing might have been:

> This could be the way to go, but can you expand some more or show an example? I think this would still require `math` functions which the question tries to avoid.

I try to start *all* comments with something nice to soften the tone. Tones don't pass very well in text. Next, I *explicitly* state what is missing from the post, and potential problems with the approach.

The comment you've received is out of line. It is not nice. It uses offensive language, and is also wrong. A 5K user is a high reputation user with moderator capabilities, and it is very common for >1K users to comment on posts of new users. It is also very common to say something is wrong without correcting it yourself - there is absolutely no problem with that.

Your response, by the way, was very good. You defused the tension effectively, you wrote well, and did not get into an argument. Well done.

Comment: Thanks. Understood, just to clarify, my intention was never to come across aggressive or combative. I was just being straight forward. However, I will take it in to consideration for the future.

Comment: @Script47 - One thing to keep in mind is that a lot of people aren't familiar with the Stack Overflow answering standards. I've seen a surprisingly high rate of improvement to short, link-based answers in response to positive, educational comments. If you start by assuming that someone is trying to be helpful, but is unaware of convention around here, I think you'll find that you'll get a good response to your comments. Kobi's example above is a great way to approach this.

Comment: (this answer is old but) I don't agree with the "rephrased" comment. The Taylor expansion formula only have exponentiation, addition, subtraction and division, none of them involve `math` functions.

Comment: @user202729 - You are right that in this particular case exponent can done in PHP using `pow`. Still, this is somewhat besides the point: the "rephrased" comment is an example on how to point on what is missing from an answer. Your comment, for example, is good information that would have been useful in the referred answer.